# Column Input Greyed out in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 6 CE to create some tables for a new schema I made.

When I create the new table, the application displays a tab which allows me to edit the table name (by default, the name is new_table), select the schema default, and add a comment for the table (though doing that seems to generate syntax errors in the generated SQL).

What it does not do is allow me to specify or configure any of the columns for the table. There is an entire column section that is completely greyed out.

I am logged in as root and root has all privileges for this schema.

Have I found a bug, or is there something special I need to do in order to allow column specification in a table???

Someone please advise...

UPDATE: Adding screenshot as requested...

[image: Screenshot of greyed out inputs (schema redacted for nondisclosure reasons)]

Comment: It's not 100% where you see this, so better add a screenshot. This is much easier than trying to explain everything in text for this type of question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you started creating a new table you can simply add columns by double clicking the empty placeholder row:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. It turns out that the only way to actually see the placeholder to click on is to maximize the application. The way I was displaying it (see the screen- shot) there was no way to see or click the placeholder. I guess I did find a bug, just not what I thought. The Oracle engineers should rethink the display logic for this screen...

Comment: You have a very small screen height it seems. But you can collapse the header in the table editor by clicking on that big gray double arrow (it's collapsed by default in modeling, but expanded in the SQL IDE).

Comment: I just encountered this same issue with the default Workbench layout! Not a small screen at all, just poor default view.

Answer (score 24):

Click on the encircled double arrow

[image: Click on the encircled double arrow]

You will now be able to edit columns. Click on any column name, grey area will become editable now.

Comment: Atleast 7-10 years years back setting up and running MySql worked like a breeze. After long time I am trying to set it up again and running into one issue or another one. Something seems to be messed up at MySql.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same prb in MySQL Worbench 6.3.6. Here is the link to the solution.
Or just drag down your Output Panel in short !

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79281

Answer (score 0):

You have to checked any key to enable the column name.
please check PK,NN, UQ, B etc then column are ready to edit.
[image]

[image]